# Screenshot from second screen

Tags: c#, winforms, screenshot

Hi I am working on a program where the user can take screenshots. The users can choose whether they want to take a screenshot from screen 1,2,3 or 4. I know how to get out the first screenshot from the first screen, but how do I get the images from screen 2,3 and 4?

My code to get the screenshot from the first screen looks like this:

```
 private void btnScreenOne_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
 {
     Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width,
         Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height);

     Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap as Image);

     graphics.CopyFromScreen(0, 0, 0, 0, bitmap.Size);

     bitmap.Save(@"C:\Users\kraqr\Documents\PrintScreens\" + 
        DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd_HH-mm-ss") + " Screen1" + 
        ".bmp", ImageFormat.Bmp);

}
```

Grateful for answers.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `Screen` class has a static property `AllScreens` which gives you an array of screens. Those objects have a `Bounds` property which you can surely use ...

Long story short: You initialize the bitmap with the size of the desired screen (don't use `PrimaryScreen`, because that's only the primary one, as the name implies) and then pass the appropriate boundaries to `CopyFromScreen`.

Comment: Now i have the boudaries from the second screen and they are as they should in copyfromscreen, but i only get the size from screen2 not the image. The image are still from screen1. Any idea?

Comment: My psychic skills tell me that you are taking the screenshot at position `(0, 0)` instead of where the second screen actually starts. See [PVitt'answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6175968/screenshot-from-second-screen/6176097#6176097) for code that should work.

Answer (score 18):

Use Screen.AllScreens instead:

```
foreach ( Screen screen in Screen.AllScreens )
{
    screenshot = new Bitmap( screen.Bounds.Width,
        screen.Bounds.Height,
        System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb );
    // Create a graphics object from the bitmap
    gfxScreenshot = Graphics.FromImage( screenshot );
    // Take the screenshot from the upper left corner to the right bottom corner
    gfxScreenshot.CopyFromScreen(
        screen.Bounds.X,
        screen.Bounds.Y, 
        0, 
        0,
        screen.Bounds.Size,
        CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy );
    // Save the screenshot
}
```

Comment: Can Screens be used without using System.Windows.Forms, I am doing this in WPF and don't want to reference System.Windows.Forms

Answer (score 7):

Use [`Screen.AllScreens`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.screen.allscreens.aspx) to retrieve the coordinates through the `Bounds` property of the specific screen and pass them to `CopyFromScreen`.